# Why is the differentiability of a piecewise defined function studied using the definition of derivative?

Tags: calculus, functions

Why is the differentiability of a piecewise defined function often studied using the definition of derivative?

For example, let:
$$\begin{align*}
 f(x)
&= x\cdot |x-1|\\
&= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcl}x (-x+1)& \text{if} & x <
1 \\ x  (x-1) & \text{if} & x \geq 1 \end{array} \right.\\
&= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcl}-x^2+x& \text{if} & x <
1 \\ x^2-x & \text{if} & x \geq 1 \end{array} \right.
\end{align*}$$

$f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R} $ except, maybe, when $x=1$:
$$\begin{align*}
 \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 1} (-x^2+x) = 0\\
\lim_{x \to
1^{+}} f(x)&= \lim_{x \to 1} (x^2 -x) = 0 \end{align*}$$

$f$ is continuous when $x=1$ because:
$$ \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^{+}} f(x) = f(1) $$

As to the differentiability at that point (by derivative's definition):

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0^{-}} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0}
\frac{\left[-(1+h)^2 + (1+h)\right] - \left[-1^2 + 1\right]}{h}\\
 &= \lim_{h\to 0}
\frac{- h(h+1)}{h} = -1\\
\strut\\
 \lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\left[(1+h)^2
- (1+h)\right] - \left[1^2 - 1\right]}{h}\\ 
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h(h+1)}{h} = 1 
\end{align*}$$

$$ \lim_{h \to 0^{-}} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} \neq \lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} $$

so $f$ is not differentiable when $x=0$.

The "second" method is:

$$ f'(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lcl} -2x + 1& \text{if} & x <
1 \\ 2x-1 & \text{if} & x > 1 \end{array} \right. $$

$$ f'(1^{-}) = -1 \neq f'(1^{+}) = 1 $$

Is there any case in which the differentiability study by using the derivative (the second method) would be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &\text{if }x\neq 0,\\
0 &\text{if }x=0.
\end{array}\right.$$

The function is differentiable at $0$, with derivative equal to $0$:
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}h\sin(\frac{1}{h}) = 0.
\end{align*}$$
However, using the "second method", we look at the derivative of $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$:
$$\left(x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)' = 2x\sin\frac{1}{x} - \cos\frac{1}{x}.$$
And
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
does not exist.
Using the method, we would incorrectly conclude that the derivative does not exist at $0$.

In general, a derivative does not have to be continuous; so the second method may yield "false negatives", functions that *are* differentiable but which the technique suggests are not.

Comment: Thanks! it solved my question. Is there any formal demonstration?

Comment: @Albert: Formal demonstration of what? I gave an example of a function for which the method gives the wrong conclusion. That constitutes a proof that the method may give the wrong conclusion.

Comment: Sorry, I just got confused: I wanted an example of a continuous function

Comment: @AlbertT. Of a continuous function that does what? The function I give *is* continuous everywhere; in fact, it's differentiable everywhere. It's the *derivative* that is not continuous.

Comment: Sorry again. I just copied the function incorrectly. Thanks for all.

Comment: @AlbertT. If you wish you can see the function by [Googling x^2*sin(1/x)](https://www.google.se/search?q=sin%281%2Fx%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:sv-SE:official&client=firefox-a#hl=sv&client=firefox-a&hs=pH1&rls=org.mozilla:sv-SE%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=x^2*sin%281%2Fx%29&oq=x^2*sin%281%2Fx%29&aq=f&aqi=g-L1g-vCL2g-jCL1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0i19j0i15i33i19l2j0i18i33i19.9293l11527l0l12468l4l4l0l0l0l1l217l655l0j3j1l4l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&fp=1&biw=1525&bih=725&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&cad=b).